# Handle catch in NodeJS DELETE endpoint on findByIdAndDelete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, try-catch

I am trying to find the best to handle a catch error in the output / response.

I have this route that deletes a game by an ID

```
router.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {

    try {
      let deleteGame = await gameModel.findByIdAndDelete(ObjectId(req.params.id)).exec();

      if (deleteGame === null) {
        res.json({ error: `No game found with id ${req.params.id}` })
      } else {
        res.json({ message: `Game ${game.name} deleted` })
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  })();
});
```

When for example the ID is in an unexpected format mongoose will return 
`Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` in the "catch"

I am not sure if it a good practice to do `res.json({ message: 'An error occured' })` in the catch - wouldn't that be for the server to log etc.?

Comment: What does f.x. stand for?

Comment: I'm guessing "for example" but it would be better to write it out...

Comment: could you tell me what Id you are passing @morten-hagh

Comment: @RajuSingh - I am sending an objectID that could look like this: "5e0f8c3193a21e3ee06ed32f" it is the ID given to the document when it is created.

Comment: And if possible could you show your gameModel.Sending error message as a json is not enough. It should have status code as well. For example: Successful delete it should be 204 and for inavalid or non-existent id 404 else 500.
Can you send me the error logs in chat box. @MortenHagh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if it a good practice to do `res.json({ message: 'An error occured' })` in the `catch` - wouldn't that be for the server to log etc.?

Well, you need to send *some* response to the request, regardless of whether you log an error on the server. So yes, it makes sense to call `res.json` from within the `catch`. The exact error you return is up to you. (Based on what you do when `deleteGame` is `null`, you probably want `error` rather than `message`, though.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will send a json response with a custom error description.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample solution for that:

```js
router.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {

    try {
      let deleteGame = await gameModel.findByIdAndDelete(ObjectId(req.params.id)).exec();

      if (deleteGame === null) {
        res.status(404).send({ error: `No game found with id ${req.params.id}` })
      } else {
        res.status(204).send({ message: `Game ${game.name} deleted`, })
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // pass this to error handler middleware, this will give 500
      next(error);
    }

  })();
});
```

Error handler middleware in server.js or index.js

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
        errors: {
            message: err.message || 'Internal Server Error!',
        },
    });
})
```